# Any cleaner way to trigger React Route change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am pretty new to React-Router, I wonder if there is a simple way to change Route, some concept like state in Angular UI Router. From the React Router official tutorial :

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/12-navigating

My understanding is: I have to manually change the url to trigger route change.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Did you take at look at the `react-router` **Link** component?

> Perhaps the most used component in your app is Link. Its almost identical to the <a/> tag you're used to except that its aware of the Router it was rendered in.

[React-Router Tutorial / Lesson 3: Navigating with Link](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/03-navigating-with-link)

Comment: thanks for reply. My goal right now is pretty simple, just click a button/image to switch view. But from the example on React Router tutorial,  it seems I need to know the whole URL and push it into browserHistory. I wonder if there is any API from React Router that allows me to defined a action with a simple state param, like in Angular UI router state.go()

Comment: So lets say you want to add a button that takes the user to a login page. Have you tried a simple `<Link to="/login">Login</Link>`? Making that link look like a button should be just a matter of styling...

Comment: I need conditionaly decide a click action, that is why I need to specify which view I should trigger

Comment: Kuan, should you need to decide which route to hit, you could simply bind the Link to your conditional logic like this: `const routeToHit = thisOrThat ? '/login' : '/some-view';`. Then, in your link, you do this: `<Link to={routeToHit}>Label<Link>`